# Is there a way to tell robots not to look at a directory?

Tags: seo

I have a directory full of images, that I do not want viewed by robots, is there a way to make this directory private?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a warning, robots.txt does not keep all robots out, but at least it won't be indexed by Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**How to Use Robots.txt in Search Engine Optimization ( SEO )**](http://takeitrightaway.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-robotstxt-in-search-engine.html)

> Type-in " Disallow: /folder name "
>   for any folder containing files you don’t want search engines to crawl.
>
> Or, type-in " Disallow: /filename.filetype "
>   for any page or file you don’t want search engines to index.

Note of the following example :

```
* Disallow: /private/
* Disallow: /private/image01.jpg
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Referenced external site with more information.  Provided summary from the site.  Added example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a robots.txt file in your site's root directory. Inside that file put

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/), and most all robots will honor your requests in your robots.txt.

You'll want something like the following:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /path/to/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /MyImageDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

In your root directory you can place a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file that forbids robots to index specific directories.

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt is only obeyed by well-behaved robots.  not all of them are well-behaved like those of the major search engines - some are written by incompetent buffoons, some are written by spammers trawling for email addresses, and so on.

anyway, you also want to turn Indexes off for that directory...either with a .htaccess file or in your apache conf like so:

```
<Directory /path/to/images/dir>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory >
```

or by by placing a blank index.html file in there.

this will stop them from seeing a directory listing of the image files.  it **won't** stop them from following direct links to the images from other pages on your site.

there's actually very little you can do to really prevent robots from accessing **public** files on your webserver that won't either inconvenience your users or increase the load on your server by only serving images through a script that only serves to logged-in users (e.g. by checking a cookie).